# Is There a Drill Grip for a Typical Dewalt Drill?

Tags: power-tools, tools, tool-selection

I recently purchased a 20V toolkit from Dewalt which included a pretty typical Dewalt drill/driver. I noticed that it doesn't have a drill drip though.

I really am a fan of drill grips for a number of reasons and don't really do any close quarters work that would prohibit using one. Are there any grips available either from DeWalt or aftermarket that would fit a typical Dewalt drill/driver?

For comparison, the 20V XR hammer drill has a 360-degree grip:
[image: Hammer Drill]

**EDIT 0:**

My DeWalt Drill Number Is: DCD780

**EDIT 1:** These are the diameter measurements for my drill (By a digital caliper):

[image: Measurements]

Comment: I don't know Dewalt drills but it's possible this can only be answered if you give the exact model number, so that prospective respondents can know for sure what size and/or shape the relevant part of the drill casing is. I do know that some cordless models are shaped in such a way that a handle can't be fitted. This may be because their lower power limits the need for a front grip, or possibly because someone in the design or decision-making departments are idiots (not joking).

Comment: Echoing Graphus, please do tell us what model you've got. There's plenty of us with bins full of dewalt to measure against...

Comment: @Graphus I added the information for the drill number.

Comment: Looking at the pics I don't see where a foregrip would attach on this model (I'm presuming the knurled piece behind the chuck needs to rotate) which is what I was expecting to see. So a modification to your preferred grip might be the needed solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Graphus mentioned in a comment that style of drill doesn't really have an area where a grip would normally attach but I thought I'd see how it went with a grip attached to the torque adjustment ring on a fairly similar drill and this is what it looked like:

[image]

I gave it a test and it actually worked pretty well because as the drill turns clockwise it's natural to press downwards on the grip which holds the torque control in the maximum / drill position. The actual grip I used was from a Dewalt DCH274 which has a fair range of adjustment so maybe you can buy one of those as a spare part, but otherwise I think any similar grip of a suitable diameter will be suitable.

Also just thought to add the grip from something like a DCD991 / DCD996 in your photo won't work because they are too small in diameter to fit onto the torque adjustment ring.

Comment: Upvoted for usefulness, but I'd opine that if the drill yanks the wrong way, you might break the clutch setting collar. (Keep in mind that the drill in question is one of the lower-end models. I'm not even sure their nicer ones want that kind of abuse.) Alternately, why not skip the side handle and use the built in clutch to prevent torqued wrists?

Answer (score 2):

My new Ridgid drill/driver grip uses 2 pinching jaws that tighten onto nubs on the drill body. My earlier Ridgid drill has a conventional 360 grip with a 55mm diameter collar. These 2 styles are common, even within the same brand. Since your Dewalt uses a 360 grip, you can measure your drill collar diameter and choose any grip that matches.

Comment: One of my friends had a friend that broke his wrist when the drill bit suddenly seized rotating at high RPM. I don't think that this would be a problem for me, it's more of a convenience thing. I just prefer the drill handles.

Comment: John, StackExchange is a Q&A site, not a regular forum where a query such as this will often be met with just this kind of "I don't find they're useful" reply. While your input may be of interest to the OP the appropriate place for it is as a Comment, or, tacked on to a formal Answer to the Question.

Comment: @Graphus John would have been downvoted so much on StackOverflow he would have been banned for this answer :D Not even joking, new users are systematically destroyed on that website until they conform to the policies.

Comment: I was offering to give away my unused drill grips. That's why I specified the diameters. But I didn't want to say out loud I was offering them, because I know and respect that this is a question-and-answer site. The grips are unused because I no longer do heavy work, plus I have Popeye arms.

Comment: Very generous of you John, but still appropriate only as a Comment :-)

Comment: @SarahSzabo yikes! I'd heard tales, but I didn't realise it was *that* bad.